# Creating Windows service to send automated email through outlook com interop

Tags: c#, windows, email, service, office-interop

I am trying to develop an application that sends automated emails through outlook and interop services and getting the following exception. below is the  code with exception.

```
 try
     {
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
     mailItem.Subject = "Details of Subject";
     mailItem.To = "example@gmail.com";
     mailItem.Body = "Automated email testing"
     // mailItem.Attachments.Add(logPath);//logPath is a string holding path to the log.txt file
     mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
     mailItem.Display(false);
     mailItem.Send();
 }
catch (Exception ex)
  {
         WriteErrorLog("\n");
         WriteErrorLog(ex.Message);
         WriteErrorLog(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

And its throwing an exception :

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj) 
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at WServiceMixInOne.ConnectionLogs.MainClass() in C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WServiceMixInOne\WServiceMixInOne\ConnectionLogs.cs:line 120
```

**Line 120** is the 1st line app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

Comment: Just to be sure. Is outlook installed on the machine and was started at least once?

Comment: What is the type of the exception being thrown?

Comment: Yes, outlook installed and configured, working okay for normal mails.
Exceptions are runtime, activator. Do i need to create an instance of outlook to access it?

Comment: `Exceptions are runtime, activator.` That is not the *Type* of the exception. Please post a screenshot of the exception that is occurring (text would be even better).

Answer (score 0):

Try closing outlook from background process. And then execute your code.

Comment: windows service does not execute. It is run as background task and log are generated in event viewer as defined by user.